# PHP Regular expression preg_replace definition missing

Tags: php, regex

I want to make user input valid , therefor i'm using regual expression.
I'd like the user to insert only alphanumeric content and some specific characters as - ,!$^& etc.
So far the code I've got is :

```
$validText = preg_replace('@[^A-Za-z0-9\w\ ]@', '',$text);
```

But it only care for alphanumeric and spaces , but how do I define the regual expression to refer to characters as .'!@# and etc ? Where do I define it ?
By the way, could you please refer me to a **good** regular expression?

Any suggesti

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add them to your group.

```
$validText = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\w .\'!@#]/', '',$text);
```

**Note:** [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) may be better suited in this case. Currently you're allowing invalid characters then removing them. Makes for a poor user experience.

Comment: Thanks , did you mean

$validText = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\w .['!@#]/', '',$text);   ?

Comment: No. They can all be in the same group. However, I should have escaped the `'`. See update.